# Unable to install some PHP packages on Alpine Linux

Tags: php, alpine-linux, php-7.1

I am trying to install some PHP packages that I use for my application in Alpine Linux. The packages that I am currently using come from the Remi repo and I install them successfully on CentOS 7, but when I try to install tthe same packages on Alpine, it says not found. An example of a package is `php-cli`.

Am I doing it right or is there a recommended way of installing packages in Alpine? I am using php7 and Alpine 3.8.

Note: I am using `php7-` prefix when I am installing a package in Alpine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For locating packages for Alpine Linux, the [Alpine package search engine](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages) is the best place to look for.

Querying for `php7*`, we can see that there are indeed no matches on the `main` Alpine V3.8 repository, but many matches on the `community` repository: [php7* package search](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=php7*&branch=v3.8&repo=community&arch=x86_64).

For installing these packages, you'll first need to add the `community` repository to your `/etc/apk/repositories` file (uncomment it, if it is commented out):

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community
```

Then, run `apk update` and `apk add php7 [additional packages...]` for installing the desired PHP 7 packages.

Specifically, `php7-cli` seems to be missing. For PHP 7 CLI tools, you could try installing `php7-dev` from the `edge` community repository. Similar to above, add the following to your `/etc/apk/repositories`, then update and install:

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

Comment: I have installed some php modules from the alpine repository. However it seems that they are note enabled. How can I enable them ? using the command docker-php-ext-enable did not work.